# Divs Images, UL

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to ditch tables and at the same time trying not to contract divitis, so am starting simple, I need a web page that has a header bar that contains a menu (horizontal width 100%) then a title bar which contains the title (left) and the logo (right)

Simple enough, I could do this in table or everything being in a its own div in a few minutes, BUT I don't want to create 3 divs (and according to "research" I shouldn't need to), So top menu is fine, title bar is fine, but getting the logo to align below the top menu but float to the right of the title text is not, I'm trying so hard not to have multiple divs (or just one around the img logo) so am looking for the best way to accomplish this.

```
<body>
<div class="DVcontainer">
<ul class="topmenu">
    <li>topmenu 1</li>
    <li>topmenu 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="maintitle">
    <li>title1</li>
    <li>title2</li>
</ul>
<div class="DVlogo">
<img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 72px; height: 72px;"  src="images/something.png" alt="Ying Yang" />
</div>


.maintitle ul {
padding:10px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
}
.maintitle li {
list-style-type: none;
}

.topmenu ul {
padding:10px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
}

.topmenu li {
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: For starters looks like you're missing a closing </div>

Comment: You are putting your titles and menus in a list but are those lists of titles and menus or are they titles and menus?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not correct.
For example:
**ul.maintitle** can be used to select ul tags with class maintitle.

So to achieve what you want using two divs, CSS will be:

```
ul.maintitle {
padding:10px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
}
.maintitle li {
list-style-type: none;
}

ul.topmenu {
padding:10px;
margin:0px;
clear:both;
}

.DVlogo{
float:right;
}
.topmenu li {
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: If you want logo just right to maintitle, use float:left in DVlogo CSS: 
    .DVlogo{float:left}